# can we release same app with 1 or 2 different functionality for 2 different countries?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to release my app in only 2 country and i want to do 2 different functionality for both country.

For example.

`ViewController1` functionality is different in Jamaica.
`ViewController1` functionality is different in Kenya.

Different functionality means content is different, or input forms are different.

Is it possible? if yes then please refer some document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on Apple - ask them.

Comment: @Chris, Instead of using UserDefault or KeyChain can i use this `Locale.current` to identify the country?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because developer-centric questions about application stores are considered off-topic here on SO as discussed in [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272166/4667835).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a screen that allows user to select their country, after that, store selected country in our app (by UserDefault or Keychain, etc...).

Based on the selected country then you can switch logic/layout to adapt the requirement above

Comment: Instead of using UserDefault or KeyChain can i use this `Locale.current` to identify the country?

Comment: You shouldnt, because use can change Locale in phone setting. One other way is checking by GPS signal to know what country the user is in.

Comment: In my app, we need to do this without asking the country selection. how can i do this?

Comment: You can use GoogleMap SDK. `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json`, parse received json then you can get the country code of given coordinate. And to get current coordinate, you can use either CLLocationManager or GoogleMap SDK.

Answer (score 0):

some notes about App Store:

1) language should / must be selected by user on Prefs, NOT in Apps.
Chances Apple will refuse apps not following above logic.

2) You could test current language / Zone using code  (see below for language)
BUT I think Apple can refuse as you use a different behaviour

3) if really you need it, You can load a different controller using Storyboards (I suggest using different storyboards AND lod them at runtime using segues and "*.soryboard" as in:

```
func ViewControllerFromStoryboardWith( name: String ) -> UIViewController {

    // we use an identifier equal to filename for now.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name) as UIViewController
    return vc
}
```

---

// test lang:

```
func currHWLanguage()->String{

    let defs : UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let languages : NSArray = defs.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! NSArray
    let current = languages[0] as! String

    // since 9.0 we get en-US etc.. so cut to 2:
    let result = (current as NSString).substring(to: 2)

    #if DEBUG
    // force to IT as a bug in simulator
    // return "IT"
    #endif

    return result.uppercased()
    //NSLog("%@", current)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem many applications are trying to solve. Basically, you have the following options:

1. Let the user choose. This is the safest option if one application contains two different configuration.
2. Try to detect location of the user. Language/Locale is unsafe because many people will have English (or different) locale set up. Very unsafe. You shouldn't ask for GPS location for this. The safest option is to create a server request and check the location using the IP address. A bit complicated and won't work if a VPN is used (e.g. antivirus apps create VPNs).
3. Create two different apps. In the end, this is the best option. Add a second application target to your project and release two separate apps with separate configuration.

Comment: Thank for your reply. can i use `locale.regionCode` to identify the country?